# Create remote file stream into terminal

Tags: vim, remote, tomcat

I'm not experienced unix user so terminology may be not correct.

Suppose I have a remote unix hosting which I'm connecting to from windows by ssh with putty.

So I have terminal window with access to some dirs on the server hoster granted access to. There is log file which content I can see with `cat` command.

My purpose is to get its content in real-time printed into console as soon as webapp (tomcat) writes to the file. Is this possible concerning limited access rights?

Comment: If you can `cat` the file, you should be able to `tail -f` (or `tail -F`) it, surely? Is that what you mean by "real-time"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29#File_monitoring

Comment: Exactly, thanks! Please post answer to mark as right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can `cat` the file, then your (read) access rights shouldn't be a limitation - in which case you should be able to use `tail -f` (or `tail -F`) to monitor the file for appended content.

This application of the `tail` utility is described quite well in the Wikipedia article: see [File monitoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29#File_monitoring)